# Android / busybox / termux test environment

Tags: android, bash, docker, busybox

I'm developping some bash scripts that run on Linux/BSD/Mac/Windows.
I'd like to port them to the busybox environment, to get them to run in an android terminal emulator, like termux.

What's the best way to get a test environment for busybox / android ?
I've tried to go with the docker busybox image.
I also need to be able to add tools like an ssh client or rsync, which works in android termux via `apt install rsync`, but won't work in a docker image for obvious reasons.

Any ideas ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Busybox itself is really just a single multicall binary that can behave like many different tools. In a pure busybox environment, you'd probably end up compiling busybox to include the applets that you need (like rsync).

In your question, you referenced a command `apt install rsync`. Busybox doesn't have an `apt` command, like you mentioned. It may be possible to install a package manager that would in turn be able to install things on demand.

The Alpine Linux distro has a very small package manager called `apk`, and it also can use busybox. The `alpine` official image on the Docker Hub essentially has just busybox and apk. Its packages are based on libmusl instead of glibc. It'd be worth taking a look at alpine for sure.

Here's how to install rsync on alpine:

```
$ docker run --rm -it alpine sh
/ # which busybox
/bin/busybox
/ # ls -lah `which mv`
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          12 Jun 23 19:37 /bin/mv -> /bin/busybox
/ # apk --no-cache add rsync
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.4/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.4/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/4) Installing libattr (2.4.47-r4)
(2/4) Installing libacl (2.2.52-r2)
(3/4) Installing popt (1.16-r6)
(4/4) Installing rsync (3.1.2-r2)
Executing busybox-1.24.2-r9.trigger
OK: 5 MiB in 15 packages
/ # ls -lah `which rsync`
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root      396.0K Apr 29 16:02 /usr/bin/rsync
/ #
```

Other tiny package managers may work as well, but I'm not aware of how easy they are to install into a stripped down busybox root (like the `busybox` image). opkg and ipkg come to mind for embedded package managers.

Comment: Great ! Works like a charm and seems close enough to android termux environment.